# How to enable proper Description reason in N1QL Couchbase in case of query failure. Or any Exception Id(Icode)?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Following is the one failure log for same id here it is mark as status as success or error in failure case.

Here it is failure case in description it mention just "A N1QL EXPLAIN statement was executed" but didnt gave proper Exception Id and proper Description details-

> {"clientContextId":"INTERNAL-b8d19563-94a1-442d-9a09-dde36743fb7d","description":"A
> N1QL EXPLAIN statement was
> executed","id":28673,"isAdHoc":true,"metrics":{"elapsedTime":"11.921ms","executionTime":"11.764ms","resultCount":1,"resultSize":649},"name":"EXPLAIN
> statement","node":"127.0.0.1:8091","real_userid":{"domain":"builtin","user":"Administrator"},"remote":{"ip":"127.0.0.1","port":44695},"requestId":"958a7e12-d5a6-4d7b-bd40-ac9bb60cf4a3","statement":"explain
> INSERT INTO `Guardium` (KEY, VALUE) \nVALUES ( "id::5554\n", { "Emp
> Name": "Test4", "Emp Company" : "GS Lab", "Emp Country" :
> "India"} )\nRETURNING
> *;","status":"errors","timestamp":"2021-01-07T09:37:00.486Z","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 (Couchbase Query Workbench
> (6.6.1-9213-enterprise))"}

Please provide input on this, I want proper description about why this N1QL failure reason in audit.logs

Thank you..

Comment: I am performing some simple insert query-->> with the same Id --> 5554

INSERT INTO `Guardium2` (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ( "EmpId::5554", { "EmpName": "test2", "EmpCompany" : "GS Lab4", "EmpCountry" : "India2"} ) RETURNING *;

This id is already present in the DB, Was accepting some proper description from Couchbase i.e Inserting duplicate Id or something which contains proper exception Id